# Polynomial interpolation over Finite Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, interpolation

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a finite field (p is prime), and consider $V = \mathrm{Span}(\{1, x^2, x^3, x^5, x^6\}) \subset  \mathbb{F}_p[x]$. What is the bound on $p$, such that there exists an interpolation set of size $5$ for $V$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$?

[Edit] An interpolation set is defined as a set of points in $\mathbb{F}_p$ so that any value of a poly in $V$ can be interpolated using its evaluations on those points. [/Edit]

My intuition is failing me on this one. say $p = 5$ then $x^6 = x$ so it means I can't interpolate the coefficient of $x^6$?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  If $\mathbb F_p$ is a finite field, then $p$ is a prime (or at least a prime power).  We certainly can't have $p=6$.  And what is an "interpolation set"?

Comment: Thanks @lulu - you're right. p is definitely prime. the interpolation set is defined as a set of points in F_p so that any value of a poly in V can be interpolated using its evaluations on those points

Comment: Please edit your post to take out the $p=6$ example.  Maybe include a real example?  Suppose $p=5$.  Then you have $5$ elements in your field.  Still not clear to me what you intend to do with them.  It is not true that any element in $V$ is determined by its values on those points, if that is what you are asking.  $x^5=x$ for every $x\in \mathbb F_5$.  Is that an example of what you are asking about?

Comment: My guess about the meaning of the question is that it asks whether we can find (obviously distinct) elements $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\in\Bbb{F}_p$ such that a polynomial from $V$ is uniquely determined by its values at the points $x_i$, and that those values can be chosen freely. This is equivalent to the matrix with rows $(x_1^j,x_2^j,x_3^j,x_4^j,x_5^j), j=0,2,3,5,6,$ having a non-zero determinant.

Comment: That determinant is the product of a Vandermonde determinant, non-zero whenever the variables $x_i$ are distinct and [a Schur polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial). Here the relevant Schur polynomial is (thanks to Mathematica)
$$S=e(2,2,1,1)+3e(2,1,1,1,1),$$ where by $e(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ I denote the symmetric polynomial in the five variables gotten by symmetrizing $\prod_ix_i^{a_i}$. So $e(2,2,1,1)$ is the sum of the $30$ terms like $x_1^2x_2^2x_3x_4$ with all permutations of indices, and $e(2,1,1,1,1)$ is the sum of $5$ terms like $x_1^2x_2x_3x_4x_5$.

Comment: Whenever $p$ is large enough such quintuples will obviously exist. I don't know how large is "large enough" in the present case. Anyway, please comment whether I'm making any sense:-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - your understanding of the question is what I make of it too. I need to determine whether p is large enough to so Fp contains 5 elements that evaluating in poly in V over them is enough to determine V's evaluation on any element.
However I'm not sure I follow how you can project the value of p to the calculations you presented above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of the question is that it asks for a collection of five distinct elements $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\in\Bbb{F}_p$ such that for all $5$-tuples $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5)\in\Bbb{F}_p^5$ the system of equations $f(x_i)=y_i, i=1,2,3,4,5$, is satisfied by a unique polynomial $f(x)\in V$.

My understanding may be wrong for that variant turned out being a bit duller than I initially anticipated. Here comes anyway.

> This is possible if and only if $p>5$.

The problem is equivalent to our ability to uniquely solve the coefficients $a_i\in\Bbb{F}_p, i=0,2,3,5,6,$ of the polynomial
$$
f(x)=a_0+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_5x^5+a_6x^6
$$
subject to the linear system of five equations
$$
f(x_i)=y_i, i=1,2,3,4,5.
$$
The matrix of that system of equations is
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&x_1^2&x_1^3&x_1^5&x_1^6\\
1&x_2^2&x_2^3&x_2^5&x_2^6\\
1&x_3^2&x_3^3&x_3^5&x_3^6\\
1&x_4^2&x_4^3&x_4^5&x_4^6\\
1&x_5^2&x_5^3&x_5^5&x_5^6
\end{array}\right).
$$
If we used terms of degrees $0,1,2,3,4$ instead of $0,2,3,5,6$, then

1. the answer would be given by the Lagrange interpolation formula,
2. the matrix of the system would be the familiar Vandermonde matrix with the well known determinant
   $$
   \Delta=\left\vert\begin{array}{ccccc}
   1&x_1&x_1^2&x_1^3&x_1^4\\
   1&x_2&x_2^2&x_2^3&x_2^4\\
   1&x_3&x_3^2&x_3^3&x_3^4\\
   1&x_4&x_4^2&x_4^3&x_4^4\\
   1&x_5&x_5^2&x_5^3&x_5^4
   \end{array}\right\vert=\prod_{1\le i<j\le5}(x_i-x_j),
   $$
3. implying that any collection of five distinct elements $x_i, i=1,2,3,4,5$ will do.

The variant limiting the range of degrees of terms to a sequence other $0,1,2,3,4$ actually does not change the conclusion very much.

- The cases $p=2,3$ are obviously out for we don't have enough elbow room to pick five distinct elements $x_i$.
- The case $p=5$ fails for a slightly more interesting reason. By Little Fermat $x^6=x^2$ for every element $x\in\Bbb{F}_5$. Therefore the second and the last columns of $M$ coincide, implying that $\det M=0$. Less interestingly, the essentially only possibility $x_i=i-1,i=1,2,3,4,5,$ doesn't work.
- However, plugging in $x_1=0,x_2=1,x_3=2,x_4=3,x_5=4$ gives
  $$\det M=2^8\cdot 3^3\cdot5\cdot7,$$ implying that this choice works for every $p>7$.
- Instead, plugging in  $x_1=0,x_2=1,x_3=2,x_4=3,x_5=5$ gives
  $$\det M=2^6\cdot3^3\cdot5^2\cdot41,$$
  implying that this choice works for every $p>5$ other than $p=41$.

Together the last two bullets give the claim: one of them works for every prime $p>5$.

---

More interesting/general variants can possibly be handled by studying suitable [Schur polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial). We easily see that the Vandermonde determinant $\Delta$ is always a factor of $\det M$, no matter the choice of sequence of exponents. The Schur polynomials are exactly the quotients $\det M/\Delta$. The non-vanishing of the Schur polynomial tells us whether a given choice of $x_i$s works (in a more general version we may have more terms).

Comment: can you please explain the part where you plug in the examples? you manually calculate the determinant (not with the Vandermonde matrix formula)? why does the first calculation means the determinant is not zero for every p > 7? since for p = 7 , 7 is the zero element in F7?

Comment: @ShaharA I used Mathematica to calculate those determinants. With the Schur polynomial it could be done manually as well (including $0$ among the $x_i$s implies that most of the terms vanish). The point is that $\det M=0$ in $\Bbb{F}_p$ if and only if $p$ is a factor of $\det M$ when viewed as an integer.